# Can't figure out how to enter a playAgain loop

Tags: loops, while-loop

This program is suppose to be a game where I ask the user for 2 numbers low and high it can be in any order. The generator will create a random number between those 2 numbers and will continue asking the user for a number, until they get the answer. 
The only problem I have is prompting the user if the user wants to playAgain:
This is my code I have right now.

```
import java.util.*;

public class tester
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Scanner S = new Scanner(System.in);                                                                                                                             //Introduction Statement to game
        System.out.println("This is a guessing game.  I will ask you for two numbers.");
        System.out.println("I will choose a random number between your two numbers for you " + "\n" + "to try and guess.  As you guess, I will give you hints.");

        System.out.print("Choose two numbers to bound your range: ");                                                                                                   //Scanner to store user's input for the range
        int u1 = S.nextInt();
        int u2 = S.nextInt();
        int guess;
        int count = 0; // = 0 new
        String playAgain = "Y";

        int high;
        int low;
        if(u1 < u2)
        {
            high = u2;
            low = u1;
        }
        else
        {
            high = u1;
            low = u2;
        }
        Random gen = new Random();
        int rand = gen.nextInt(high-low+1) + low;
        System.out.println("Now guess a number between " + low + " and " + high + ": ");
        guess = S.nextInt();

        while (playAgain.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
        {
                System.out.println("Now guess a number between " + low + " and " + high + ": ");
                guess = S.nextInt();
                while(guess != rand)
                {
                count++;
                if (guess > high || guess < low)
                {
                    System.out.println("Out of range. Please follow the directions dumb-ass.");
                }
                else if(guess > rand)
                {
                    high = guess;
                    System.out.println("Too high!");
                }
                else
                {
                    low = guess;
                    System.out.println("Too low!");
                }
                System.out.print("Now guess a number between " + low + " and " + high + ": ");
                guess = S.nextInt();
                if(guess == rand)
                {
                    System.out.println("you got it!.");
                }
                    else if(count == 10)
                {
                    System.out.println("You lost! So Sorry.");
                    //break;
                }
            System.out.println("Would you like to play again? Enter Y to play or any other key to quit: ");
            S.nextLine();
            playAgain = S.nextLine();
                }
        }
}
}
```

Comment: Why do you have `S.nextLine()` first and the
            `playAgain = S.nextLine();` ?. Looking at your code it looks like you just need `playAgain = S.nextLine();` and you don't need the first `S.nextLine()`

Comment: I have no idea, I copied the playAgain code from some other user to see if it would work on my program. It seems S.nextLine(); allows me to get the input of the user. While playAgain = S.nextLine(); doesn't do anything? I commented out S.nextLine(); it caused my program to end.

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 nested loops instead of just 1.

```
String playAgain = "Y";
while(playAgain.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
{
    Scanner S = new Scanner(System.in);                                                                                                                                  
    //Introduction Statement to game
    System.out.println("This is a guessing game.  I will ask you for two numbers.");
    System.out.println("I will choose a random number between your two numbers for you " + "\n" + "to try and guess.  As you guess, I will give you hints.");

    System.out.print("Choose two numbers to bound your range: ");                                                                                                   //Scanner to store user's input for the range
    int u1 = S.nextInt();
    int u2 = S.nextInt();
    int guess;
    int count = 0; // = 0 new

    int high;
    int low;

    int gameHasEnded = 0;
    while(!gameHasEnded)
    {
        // do game stuff here; after he won or lost, set gameHasEnded = 1
    }
    System.out.println("Would you like to play again? Enter Y to play or any other key to quit: ");
    S.nextLine();
    playAgain = S.nextLine();
```

This way you distinguish the two events (1) game has ended (for whatever reason) and (2) play it again or not.

Comment: What do you mean set GameHasEnded = 1?

Comment: Well, there are 2 conditions when the game has ended: (1) The player guessed the right number or (2) he tried 10 times. In both cases the game ends, so you set the variable gameHasEnded to 1. Therefore the inner loop will break and the player is presented with the choice to play again.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put the code inside your while, in a function.

After your new function executes, if the user input equals Y you execute it again

Else you just return ^^